# INOI 2015 - Periodic Strings

Tags: c++, algorithm

Question: https://www.codechef.com/INOIPRAC/problems/INOI1502

Here's what I'd thought off -

- Have a function, f(n) which finds the factors of n
- If a factor, i, is found, call f(i)
- for each value of n, the function also calculates the number of non periodic strings would be equal to 2^n - (the value returned by each of the function calls)
- return the number of non periodic strings and store this number in an array to prevent

Then I just call the function, f(n) modulo n to get the output

It works for smaller values, but not for larger ones

For example, when n=35 & m=99999989

My code as of now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int arr[150100];
int ans[150100];
int check(int n){
    if(arr[n]>0){
        return arr[n];
    }
    else if(n == 1){
        arr[n] = 2;
        return 2;
    }
   if(n==2){
       arr[n] = 2;
       return 2;
    }
    for(int i =1 ;i<(n/2) +1;i++){
     
        if(n%i == 0){
            ans[n] -= check(i);//2+
        }
    }
    
    arr[n] = ans[n];
    return ans[n];
}
int main() {
    int n,m;
    cin>>n>>m;
    for(int i=0;i<=150100;i++){
        arr[i] = 0;
        ans[i] = pow (2,i);
    }
    std::cout<<( check(n) )%m<<endl;
}
```

---

#### Full problem statement:

> A string is any nonempty sequence of `0`s and `1`s. Examples of strings are `00`, `101`, `111000`, `1`, `0`, `01`. The *length* of a string is the number of symbols in it. For example, the length of `111000` is 6. If *u* and *v* are strings, then *uv* is the string obtained by concatenating *u* and *v*. For example if *u* = `110` and *v* = `0010` then *uv* = `1100010`.
>
> A string *w* is *periodic* if there exists a string *v* such that *w* = *v<sup>n</sup>* = *vv · · · v* (*n* times), for some *n* ≥ 2. Note that in this case the length of *v* is strictly less than that of *w*. For example, `110110` is periodic, because it is *vv* for *v* = `110`.
>
> Given a positive integer `N` , find the number of strings of length `N` which are not periodic. Report the answer modulo `M`. The non-periodic strings of length 2 are `10` and `01`. The non- periodic strings of length 3 are `001`, `010`, `011`, `100`, `101`, and `110`.
>
> #### Input format
>
> A single line, with two space-separated integers, `N` and `M`.

Comment: What kind of "not working" are we talking about? Incorrect results? Crash?

Comment: `int arr[150100];` and `for(int i=0;i<=150100;i++){` then `arr[i] = 0;` off by 1 error here. `arr[150100]` is out of bounds. The Undefined behavior from this could cause incorrect results.

Comment: Yep, incorrect results

Comment: @drescherjm woops, fixed that. But it doesn't really change the answer as that's basically an array that checks if something already's been calculated

Comment: This type of Undefined behavior can cause other variables to be corrupted. `ans[0]` may be initialized to 0 instead of 1 because of this mistake.

Comment: But ans[0] doesn't really matter, as we'll never end up visiting it. We return a value the moment we reach 1, and the loop starts at 1 too, instead of 0

Comment: I'm not thrilled about that `pow(2,i)`. `pow` is for floating-point exponentiation, it will first lose precision then overflow if its operand gets too big. Which it does, since 2 to the power of 150,000-something requires as many bits to store, and your `int` type probably only has 32. Hence, signed overflow, formal UB and garbled results. The fact that the answer is requested in modular arithmetic certainly hints at a mathematical property which enables you to find it without actually computing these humonguous numbers.

Comment: I changed it to long long instead, but it still doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll start from built in type you have choose, it's not the best choice for your example: n=35 & m=99999989. Generally size of int is 32 bits, so it capable to hold maximum 2^32. So for your example you should choose a type that capable to hold minimum 35 bits.

Long long is also not good choice since you use modulo function which applies on integers, if you want to apply modulo on type bigger than int, you will prefer to use function fmod, please see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/.

In your implementation I would prefer to use double type, on most systems it's size is 64 bits, below is code with some corrections:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
double arr[150100];
double ans[150100];
double check(int n){
    if(arr[n]>0){
        return arr[n];
    }
    else if(n == 1){
        arr[n] = 2;
        return 2;
    }
    if(n==2){
       arr[n] = 2;
       return 2;
    }
    for(int i =1 ;i<(n/2) +1;i++){

        if(n%i == 0){
            ans[n] -= check(i);//2+
        }
    }

    arr[n] = ans[n];
    return ans[n];
}
int main() {
    int n,m;
    cin>>n>>m;
    for(int i=0;i < 150100;i++){
        arr[i] = 0;
        ans[i] = pow(2.0,i);
    }
    std::cout<<static_cast<int>(fmod(check(n),m))<<endl;
}
```

Please note that this fix will work only for N up to 64, because on most systems double size is 64 bits.

The second issue that you should take into account is your "ans" array, you try to initialize it with values that are much more bigger than int or double capable to hold, values that are bigger than 2^64. in this case there will be truncated data in "ans".

For this task I would prefer another approach which includes modular exponentiation rules: ab mod m = (a mod m)(b mod m) mod m = (a(b mod m)) mod m

According to description in question 2 ≤ M ≤ 10^8, so it's enough to hold array of integers in this task. 
For example, to calculate 2^150000 mod 10^8, instead of evaluating 2^150000 directly, do it step by step and take modulo at each step.